# itemize in table without excess space

Tags: tables, spacing, itemize

I am trying to create a list of bullet points in a tabular environment. When I use itemize, the line separating different jobs on my cv is no longer separated. When I manually use cdot however, the text on the second line does not align with the text on the first line.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bf{}\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{10pt} % Spacing around section

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{R{2cm}|p{12cm} R{5cm}}
 \textsc{Jun-Aug} & \textbf{Job 1} & place, \textsc{Netherlands}\\
\textsc{2014}&  \emph{Position name}&\\
&$\cdot$ Here goes all the text that I want to align at on the second line with the alignment on the first line&\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
 \textsc{Jun-Jul}& \textbf{Job 2} & Paris, \textsc{France}\\
 \textsc{2013}&  \emph{Position name}&\\
& $\cdot$ Responsible for followed by a list of things I was responsible for&\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Where is your `itemize`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `calc` package as below.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bf{}\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{10pt} % Spacing around section

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\custombullet{\hspace*{-1ex}\parbox{1ex}{$\cdot$ }}

\begin{document}

\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{R{2cm}|p{12cm} R{5cm}}
 \textsc{Jun-Aug} & \textbf{Job 1} & place, \textsc{Netherlands}\\
\textsc{2014}&  \emph{Position name}&\\
&\custombullet Here goes all the text that I want to align at on the second line with the alignment on the first line&\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
 \textsc{Jun-Jul}& \textbf{Job 2} & Paris, \textsc{France}\\
 \textsc{2013}&  \emph{Position name}&\\
& \custombullet Responsible for followed by a list of things I was responsible for&\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: example of code]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, using the `makecell` package (allows linebreak inside cells,and common formatting defined in preamble), booktabs (the `\addlinespace` is simpler to use than an empty `\multicolumn{3}{c}{}` and does the same job).

I supposed the second column will contain only jobs description. To simplify typing, I defined a `job` counter and a `J` column type that inserts automatically `Job n`, then begins an `itemize` environment. All you have to do is typing `\position{…}` that produces the position name in italic and inserts a small vertical spacing, then \item and the description of the job.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bf{}\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{10pt} % Spacing around section
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellset{\scshape}
\renewcommand\cellalign{tr}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcounter{job}
\newcommand\job{\refstepcounter{job}\textbf{\color{LightSkyBlue2}Job \thejob}}
\newcommand\position[1]{\item[\emph{#1}]\leavevmode\smallskip}

\newcolumntype{J}{>{\arraybackslash\job\itemize[wide=0pt, nosep, label= \color{LightSkyBlue2}\textbullet]}X<{\mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\enditemize}}

\begin{document}

\section{Work Experience}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\scshape} r!{\color{LightSkyBlue2}\vrule width 2pt}Jr}
\makecell{Jun-Aug\\2014} &
\position{First position name}%
\item Here goes all the text that I want to align at on the second line with the alignment on the first line.
& place, \textsc{Netherlands}\\
\addlinespace[3ex]
 \makecell{Jun-Jul\\2013}&
 \position{Second position name}
\item Responsible for followed by a list of things I was responsible for.
& Paris, \textsc{France}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]